# PyQt5: Resizable `QGraphicsRectItem`: How to properly update its position (in scene coordinate)

Tags: python, pyqt5, qgraphicsitem, qgraphicsrectitem

I create a resizable `QGraphicsRectItem`, I am able to resize it just fine, but I am not able to update the position of the new resized item in its scene

```
import typing
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPen, QBrush, QColor, QResizeEvent
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRectF, QSize
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QGraphicsView, QGraphicsScene, QGraphicsItem, QGraphicsRectItem, QMainWindow, QVBoxLayout, QWidget

class ResizableRect(QGraphicsRectItem):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super().__init__(*args)
        self.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable, True)
        self.setPen(QPen(QBrush(QColor('blue')), 5))
        self.selected_edge = None
        self.click_pos = self.click_rect = None

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        """ The mouse is pressed, start tracking movement. """
        self.click_pos = event.pos()
        self.newY = self.pos().y()
        rect = self.rect()
        if abs(rect.left() - self.click_pos.x()) < 5:
            self.selected_edge = 'left'
        elif abs(rect.right() - self.click_pos.x()) < 5:
            self.selected_edge = 'right'
        elif abs(rect.top() - self.click_pos.y()) < 5:
            self.selected_edge = 'top'
        elif abs(rect.bottom() - self.click_pos.y()) < 5:
            self.selected_edge = 'bottom'
        else:
            self.selected_edge = None
        self.click_pos = event.pos()
        self.click_rect = rect
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        """ Continue tracking movement while the mouse is pressed. """
        # Calculate how much the mouse has moved since the click.
        pos = event.pos()
        x_diff = pos.x() - self.click_pos.x()
        y_diff = pos.y() - self.click_pos.y()

        # Start with the rectangle as it was when clicked.
        rect = QRectF(self.click_rect)

        # Then adjust by the distance the mouse moved.
        if self.selected_edge is None:
            rect.translate(x_diff, y_diff)
        elif self.selected_edge == 'top':
            rect.adjust(0, y_diff, 0, 0)
            # Test when resize rectangle upward; not working properly for now
            if y_diff < 0:              
                    newCenter = (rect.bottom() - pos.y()) / 2
                    self.newY = self.pos().y() - newCenter

        elif self.selected_edge == 'left':
            rect.adjust(x_diff, 0, 0, 0)
        elif self.selected_edge == 'bottom':
            rect.adjust(0, 0, 0, y_diff)
        elif self.selected_edge == 'right':
            rect.adjust(0, 0, x_diff, 0)


        # Also check if the rectangle has been dragged inside out.
        if rect.width() < 5:
            if self.selected_edge == 'left':
                rect.setLeft(rect.right() - 5)
            else:
                rect.setRight(rect.left() + 5)
        if rect.height() < 5:
            if self.selected_edge == 'top':
                rect.setTop(rect.bottom() - 5)
            else:
                rect.setBottom(rect.top() + 5)

        # Finally, update the rect that is now guaranteed to stay in bounds.
        self.setY(self.newY)
        self.setRect(rect)

        
    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event): # for printing only i.e., after resizing
        print(f"item.pos(): {self.pos()}")


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        central = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(central)

        self.rect = ResizableRect(-100, -50, 200, 100)
        scene = QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 300, 300)
        scene.addItem(self.rect)
        self.view = QGraphicsView(central)
        self.view.setScene(scene)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(central)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()

    app.exec_()


main()
```

For now, I am testing updating `item.pos()` when resize upward only, It is not working properly and I need advice to correct this implementation. In `mouseMoveEvent()`, when `self.selected_edge == top`, I calculate the center of the new rectangle. Then I compute the `newY` value that I will use to update the item's position in scene later on, i.e., `self.setY(self.newY)`. The result is that the item keeps moving upward as I resize. Where did I do wrong?

Thank you for helping!

Comment: Well, the first problem is that you're creating an item with a rectangle at relative coordinates *and* set its position. This creates confusion as you're also trying to use both `setPos()` *and* `setRect()` using the wrong reference. Besides, you cannot set a layout on a QMainWindow, so remove that `setLayout()` which is pointless anyway, since you're already creating the layout for the central widget.

Comment: @musicamante, you're right, I remove the `setLayout()` and `setPos(200, 200)`, and update my code. Did I not do the calculation correctly to update the item's position in its scene.

Comment: You have to choose if the top and left resizing only change the rectangle of the item, or its position. Remember: the rectangle of QGraphicsRectItem is always expressed in local coordinates: an item created with `100, 100, 50, 50` will appear the same as one created with `0, 0, 50, 50` and *then* moved at `100, 100`, but they are **not** the same. Specifically, the coordinates of the mouse event will always be relative to the item position: with the cases above, clicking on the center of the rectangle will give `125, 125` in the first case, and `25, 25` in the second.

Comment: I understand about the coordination difference now, but I don't get what you mean by _"You have to choose if the top and left resizing only change the rectangle of the item, or its position."_ Does it mean I am not able to update the new rectangle and the item's position in scene at the same time?

Comment: No, you are, but you have to be careful in setting the position of the item and geometry of the rectangle. I'm writing you an answer, just hang on for some minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important aspect that is often misunderstood is the [coordinate system](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system) used for graphics items.

While the documentation addresses three "major" coordinate systems, it's important to understand that:

- items that are *children* of an item have their `pos()` relative to their parent;
- any *item* coordinate (local) is relative to the item position;

The documentation addresses this in the primitive functions (like `addRect()`):

> the item's geometry is provided in item coordinates, and its position is initialized to (0, 0)

This is extremely important to understand, especially when dealing with mouse events.

Let's suppose you make a QGraphicsRectItem subclass and create two instances of them:

- `itemA`: created with a simple `myRectItem(100, 50, 300, 200)`;
- `itemB`: created with `myRectItem(0, 0, 300, 200)` and then *moved* with `itemB.setPos(100, 50)`;

If you implement the `mousePressEvent()` in that class and print the `event.pos()`, you will see two very different results. Suppose you click in the center of those items:

- `itemA` will show `QPointF(250, 150)`;
- `itemB` will show `QPointF(150, 100)`;

This is because the position is in *item coordinates*: while the rectangle of `itemB` is always starting from `(0, 0)` (the origin point of the item), the rectangle of `itemB` is actually "translated" from the item position, so you get the point relative to the rectangle, added by the position of that rectangle.

If you want to allow resizing on all edges of an item, you must consider these aspects, and also decide if the resizing should actually change the item position **or** the geometry of its rectangle.

The most common and suggested way is to use the first approach, as it's usually more consistent and immediate.
The only difference is about choosing the origin point of the item, which just depends on your needs: generally you just have contents that start from the item origin point and go bottom-right (similarly to how windows behave), but in some cases the contents should be "around" the center of the item position (common for "control points").

Finally, resizing of a rectangle should normally consider its *corners*. A good approach doesn't use strings to identify the "side", but integer values, or, even better, *bitwise* values. Qt provides some basic enums that allow `OR` combinations, and we can use the [`Qt.Edges`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#Edge-enum) flag for our needs.

In this way not only we can provide resizing from corners, but also set appropriate cursors for the item that add visual hints about the resizing feature.

In the following code I've implemented all of the above and further more, considering:

- the existing implementation for `ItemIsMovable` (which you ignored by completely overriding it in the `mouseMoveEvent()`);
- pen size (border detection *must* be based on the pen width);
- variable content positioning (set at `(0, 0)` or around the center);
- mouse cursor changes whenever it moves to an edge or corner of the item;

```py
class ResizableRect(QGraphicsRectItem):
    selected_edge = None
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, onCenter=False):
        if onCenter:
            super().__init__(-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height)
        else:
            super().__init__(0, 0, width, height)
        self.setPos(x, y)
        self.setFlags(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
        self.setAcceptHoverEvents(True)
        self.setPen(QPen(QBrush(Qt.blue), 5))

        # a child item that shows the current position; note that this is only
        # provided for explanation purposes, a *proper* implementation should
        # use the ItemSendsGeometryChanges flag for *this* item and then
        # update the value within an itemChange() override that checks for
        # ItemPositionHasChanged changes.
        self.posItem = QGraphicsSimpleTextItem(
            '{}, {}'.format(self.x(), self.y()), parent=self)
        self.posItem.setPos(
            self.boundingRect().x(), 
            self.boundingRect().y() - self.posItem.boundingRect().height()
        )

    def getEdges(self, pos):
        # return a proper Qt.Edges flag that reflects the possible edge(s) at
        # the given position; note that this only works properly as long as the
        # shape() override is consistent and for *pure* rectangle items; if you
        # are using other shapes (like QGraphicsEllipseItem) or items that have
        # a different boundingRect or different implementation of shape(), the
        # result might be unexpected.
        # Finally, a simple edges = 0 could suffice, but considering the new
        # support for Enums in PyQt6, it's usually better to use the empty flag
        # as default value.

        edges = Qt.Edges()
        rect = self.rect()
        border = self.pen().width() / 2

        if pos.x() < rect.x() + border:
            edges |= Qt.LeftEdge
        elif pos.x() > rect.right() - border:
            edges |= Qt.RightEdge
        if pos.y() < rect.y() + border:
            edges |= Qt.TopEdge
        elif pos.y() > rect.bottom() - border:
            edges |= Qt.BottomEdge

        return edges

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.selected_edge = self.getEdges(event.pos())
            self.offset = QPointF()
        else:
            self.selected_edge = Qt.Edges()
        super().mousePressEvent(event)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.selected_edge:
            mouse_delta = event.pos() - event.buttonDownPos(Qt.LeftButton)
            rect = self.rect()
            pos_delta = QPointF()
            border = self.pen().width()

            if self.selected_edge & Qt.LeftEdge:
                # ensure that the width is *always* positive, otherwise limit
                # both the delta position and width, based on the border size
                diff = min(mouse_delta.x() - self.offset.x(), rect.width() - border)
                if rect.x() < 0:
                    offset = diff / 2
                    self.offset.setX(self.offset.x() + offset)
                    pos_delta.setX(offset)
                    rect.adjust(offset, 0, -offset, 0)
                else:
                    pos_delta.setX(diff)
                    rect.setWidth(rect.width() - diff)
            elif self.selected_edge & Qt.RightEdge:
                if rect.x() < 0:
                    diff = max(mouse_delta.x() - self.offset.x(), border - rect.width())
                    offset = diff / 2
                    self.offset.setX(self.offset.x() + offset)
                    pos_delta.setX(offset)
                    rect.adjust(-offset, 0, offset, 0)
                else:
                    rect.setWidth(max(border, event.pos().x() - rect.x()))

            if self.selected_edge & Qt.TopEdge:
                # similarly to what done for LeftEdge, but for the height
                diff = min(mouse_delta.y() - self.offset.y(), rect.height() - border)
                if rect.y() < 0:
                    offset = diff / 2
                    self.offset.setY(self.offset.y() + offset)
                    pos_delta.setY(offset)
                    rect.adjust(0, offset, 0, -offset)
                else:
                    pos_delta.setY(diff)
                    rect.setHeight(rect.height() - diff)
            elif self.selected_edge & Qt.BottomEdge:
                if rect.y() < 0:
                    diff = max(mouse_delta.y() - self.offset.y(), border - rect.height())
                    offset = diff / 2
                    self.offset.setY(self.offset.y() + offset)
                    pos_delta.setY(offset)
                    rect.adjust(0, -offset, 0, offset)
                else:
                    rect.setHeight(max(border, event.pos().y() - rect.y()))

            if rect != self.rect():
                self.setRect(rect)
                if pos_delta:
                    self.setPos(self.pos() + pos_delta)
        else:
            # use the default implementation for ItemIsMovable
            super().mouseMoveEvent(event)

        self.posItem.setText('{},{} ({})'.format(
            self.x(), self.y(), self.rect().getRect()))
        self.posItem.setPos(
            self.boundingRect().x(), 
            self.boundingRect().y() - self.posItem.boundingRect().height()
        )

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.selected_edge = Qt.Edges()
        super().mouseReleaseEvent(event)

    def hoverMoveEvent(self, event):
        edges = self.getEdges(event.pos())
        if not edges:
            self.unsetCursor()
        elif edges in (Qt.TopEdge | Qt.LeftEdge, Qt.BottomEdge | Qt.RightEdge):
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeFDiagCursor)
        elif edges in (Qt.BottomEdge | Qt.LeftEdge, Qt.TopEdge | Qt.RightEdge):
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeBDiagCursor)
        elif edges in (Qt.LeftEdge, Qt.RightEdge):
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeHorCursor)
        else:
            self.setCursor(Qt.SizeVerCursor)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        scene = QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 300, 300)
        self.view = QGraphicsView(scene)

        self.rect = ResizableRect(0, 50, 200, 100, True)
        scene.addItem(self.rect)

        central = QWidget()

        layout = QVBoxLayout(central)
        layout.addWidget(self.view)

        self.setCentralWidget(central)
```

Comment: I do not believe the implementation updates the item's position to its center. in your `mouseMoveEvent` at `topEdge`, when you `setHeight(rect.height()-diff)`, the item's position is no longer the center of its rectangle. Later on, you move it by `self.setPos(self.pos() + pos_delta)`, this also does not bring the position to its new center.

Comment: I reimplement resizing top edge by calculating a new rectangle with the same width and `newHeight = rect.height()-diff`; set the rectangle to its center by `rect = QRectF(-newWidth/2, -newHeight/2, newWidth, newHeight)`. this will center the new rectangle to its position. Then I will need to move vertically by `pos_delta.setY(diff/2)`. This ensures the position is updated to its center, but the resize seems to be more than the mouse move. Still trying to figure why..

Comment: @MinhTNguyen well spotted. And that's another reason for which having items with negative coordinates (like positioning around the center) is generally avoided, as it makes things much more complex especially for resizing purposes. The problem you're facing is caused by the fact that proper repositioning also changes the event pos coordinates (remember, they are *always* relative to the item position), so you get inconsistent mouse event positions. See the update.

Comment: You provided the perfect answer.